# How to install azure-cli on Visual Studio Online Environment

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, azure-cli, debian-buster

Any ideas how to get azure-cli working inside Visual Studio Online Environment?

I tried install via official docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-apt?view=azure-cli-latest

```
echo "deb https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ buster main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list
```

And try to install

```
vsonline:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-get install azure-cli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package azure-cli is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'azure-cli' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved by manually putting different package from Debian stretch version, and I can confirm that az login now works in Visual Studio Online environment :)

```
echo "deb https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ stretch main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install azure-cli
```

Comment: I also think, that new Visual Studio Online Enviornments, have fixed the issue and is working out of the box now.